# Which event is fired when asp.net page is loaded in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to fire a method in my asp.net page. Condition is that this method has to fire when page is loaded in client’s browser and client can see it. What  I can do in server side and what I can do in client side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery to determine if the page is loaded very easily client-side;

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    //page is fully loaded and ready, do stuff here
}
```

Server-Side: You can utilize a combination of a WebMethod, JSON, and Javascript (AJAX)

Concept Client-Side:

```
//////INLINE YOUR ASPX PAGE
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConsumeWebService()
{
     SampleService.TehMethod();
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    //page is fully loaded and ready, do stuff here
}
</script>
//////////////////
```

Concept Server-Side:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="SampleService" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class SampleService: System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void TehMethod()
    {
        //do stuff server-side here
    }

}
```

Here is a more in depth article on the process http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515101.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The server doesn't know when the browser shows the page.
However, you can include an image pointing to a server-side script.

On the client, you can use the `load` event.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the quickest and easiest way for you to achieve to automatically run server-side code is to wrap part of your page in an UpdatePanel and the set a Timer control to trigger the UpdatePanel to postback and run your code.

See [this link](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/using_the_ajax_timer_control_a.html) for an example of [using the Timer control to trigger an UpdatePanel](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/using_the_ajax_timer_control_a.html)

The above solution will load the page and then your client see the page appear to be updated dynamically.  Now, if you really need your client to *see* what is going on then once the page loads, you will need to run code on the client that calls a webservice on the server that will run your code.

Answer (score 4):

You could also decorate the your method as a webmethod and call it via javascript when the page has finished loading.

Comment: While this is a more "manual" way of doing things, it's much more efficient than using UpdatePanels - if you're planning to do any serious ASP.NET coding (or web development in general) it's definitely worth looking into web services. See [How to: Use the WebMethod Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx.aspx), [Code Model for Web Services in Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68zt3df9.aspx), and [How to: Access XML Web Services from a Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45fez2a8.aspx)

Comment: @Tulio: and if he's doing web services, he should use WCF, not old ASMX services.